# Resolvable $(10,2,1)$-design

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

I need to construct a resolvable $(10,2,1)$-design and it's parallel classes. The design itself is easy to construct but I don't know how to construct the parallel classes. I know that since $r=9$ (number of blocks containing a given point), we have $9$ parallel classes. Using symbols $0-9$, let $\mathcal{D}$ be the resolvable $(10,2,1)$-design:
$$\mathcal{D}=\{01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,34,35,36,37,38,39,45,46,47,48,49,56,57,58,59,67,68,69,78,79,89\}$$
Can someone show me how to construct the parallel classes $\mathcal{D}_1,\mathcal{D}_2,...,\mathcal{D}_9$?

Comment: What have you tried? It is useful to think of this design as a graph, since your block size is 2; it is just the complete graph $K_{10}$ on 10 vertices. Then you are looking for a 1-factorization of this graph (a partition of the edge into 1-factors).

Comment: For example, if you look up "1-factorizations of complete graphs" you can find many results. I don't know your background, so I don't know which constructions you will understand. But there are likely to be **many** different ways to construct these parallel classes.

Comment: Well I just tried to logically place $01\to \mathcal{D}_1$ and $02\to \mathcal{D}_2$ and so forth and then just tried to fit in everything somehow. But yeah I don't know anything about graph theory so I don't have those intuitions. But thanks for the hint I will look into that